# Show Bottom Sheet only if Firestore field does not have a value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this in initState using scaffoldKey to show BottomSheet (there may be a better solution?)

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) => _scaffoldKey.currentState
          .showBottomSheet((context) => Info()),
    );
  }
```

But I only want to show the Bottom Sheet if a field in Firestore is empty, if it has a value I don't want to show it. I'm really struggling with this

Comment: cant you run the code that shows the bottomsheet after you checked if the value in firestore exists? correct me if im wrong, but it seems like a simple async function will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach for this kind would be to use [Providers](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).
This is a state management approach where you can choose which widget to show based on data fields.

Comment: Could I ask you to point me in the right direction? Any examples

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: Check out this example. It will help you.